# Multiple IF conditions on dataframe columns in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe with two columns: "Sex" and "Alive". What I want to do is to count how many of each gender has survived (indicated by `1` in the file). Here's my file:

```
Sex Alive
male    1
male    0
female  1
female  1
```

I tried using the following code, but it has not worked. Any hints and pointers is greatly appreciated.

```
for r in df:
    if [ (df.Sex=='male') & (df.Alive==1) ]:
        male_survival_rate += 1
    else:
        male_dead_rate += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')

#filter dataframe
males = df.loc[(df['Sex'] == 'male') & (df['Alive'] == 1)]
females  = df.loc[(df['Sex'] == 'female') & (df['Alive'] == 1)]

#get number of rows
len(males.index)
len(females.index)
```

There are better ways to do it but this one shows how to use multiple conditions while filtering a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick. I am not familiar with `loc`, so I'll look into it more.